# Recyclerview covered by BottomNavigationView in CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-coordinatorlayout, bottomnavigationview

I tried Google Support Library BottomNavigationView with a Framelayout for my Fragments .

Here are my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.bottombarnavigation.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

  <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:background="#fcfcfc"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

When i populate my Recyclerview inside the Fragment, it's content got covered up by the BottomNavigationView .

[image]

I have no idea why this happens. I look through other people tutorial and it works fine.

**EDIT**
Here is my content_main.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.bottombarnavigation.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">


<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"></FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Try this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40153446/2891686). I think attributes app:layout_anchor and app:layout_anchorGravity are missed.

Comment: @DmitriyKaluzhin i just tried it and the results are the same. recyclerview content is still behind bottomnavigationview

Comment: Have you found the answer to this problem?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here my solution, is working for me.

I have almost the same layout as you, I moved the `BottomNavigationView` out of the `CoordinatorLayout` as I don't need any animation on it.
I've aligned `BottomNavigationView` to the parent's bottom, and added `layout_above` to `CoordinatorLayout` to have it above the `BottomNavigationView` but filling all the screen.

With this configuration I fixed the overlapping issue, I hope this would help you.

Here you have my layout.

```
    <RelativeLayout         
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".ui.activities.MainActivity">

        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
                android:id="@+id/main_coordinator"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:layout_above="@+id/dashboard_navigation">

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                    android:id="@+id/main_appbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:elevation="16dp">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                        android:id="@+id/dashboard_toolbar"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/main_frame_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
                android:id="@+id/dashboard_navigation"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                app:itemTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
                app:menu="@menu/menu_main"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Wasted so much time to fix this issue, finally such a simple trick fixes the problem. Thanks for sharing...

Answer (score 6):

One of the most useful feature of `CoordinatorLayout` is view dodging.

Child views of the `CoordinatorLayout` can be assigned as "insetting" an edge.
Any other child view that you assign as dodging that same edge will then be adjusted to suit.

In your case you would do something like the following:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

  <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include 
    layout="@layout/content_main"
    app:layout_dodgeInsetEdges="bottom" />   <-- Specifies this view dodges any views that inset the bottom edge

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:background="#fcfcfc"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation"
    app:layout_insetEdge="bottom" />      <-- Specifies that this view insets the bottom edge

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: This solve the bottom overlap issue but causes top overlap by AppBarLayout (even though appbar_scrolling_view_behavior is used)

Comment: @DanieleSegato it's not. Add `app:layout_behavior="@string/hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior"` to your `BottomNavigationView` and check what happens ))

Comment: This is the one I was looking for. Additionally: Bottom is the default layout_dodgeInsetEdges of FAB button, if you want to ignore it NONE doesn't work, so make it TOP or something else.

Comment: Toolbar is missing when applied. Any idea?

Comment: Worked for me!  Had this issue with a BottomAppBar and those settings solved it beautifully.  Would you care to link to the source for how you knew to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can put the RecyclerView and the BottomNavigationView in a LinearLayout, and then put the LinearLayout in the CoordinatorLayout. Set the attribute of RecyclerView as `layout_height="0dp"` `layout_weight="1"`, and the attribute of the BottomnavigationView as `layout_height="wrap_content"` `layout_gravity="bottom"`.

Here is part of my code, wish to help you.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/manager_main_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: If `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"` is used for toolbar, it will cause `BottomNavigationView` to be hidden when scroll down.

Comment: This doesn't allow Coordinator functions to be used on BottomNavigationView, like moving snackbars and floating actions buttons above it

Answer (score 1):

Set the recycle veiw or whatever view its in, height to 0dp and weight 1. This will make it take all the available space left.

Comment: could you put up the content_main layout?

Comment: at the include layout line, make it 0dp and weight 1. If that doesn't work then try doing it for the frame layout/relative layout

Answer (score 1):

1. Move your `BottomNavigationView` to `content_main.xml` and place it inside `RelativeLayout`
2. Add attribute `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` to `BottomNavigationView`
3. Add attribute `android:layout_above="@id/bottom_navigation"` to container `FrameLayout`

Update your layout XML's as below:

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.bottombarnavigation.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

      <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**content_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.bottombarnavigation.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#fcfcfc"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottom_navigation" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this will help~

Answer (score 1):

You can add an ItemDecorator to your recycler view that adds some padding. I'm using Kotlin instead of Java, but the general idea is:

```
 recyclerView.addItemDecoration(object : RecyclerView.ItemDecoration() {
        override fun getItemOffsets(outRect: Rect?, view: View?, parent: RecyclerView?, state: RecyclerView.State?) {
            // Get the position of the view in the recycler view
            val position = parent?.getChildAdapterPosition(view)
            if (position == null || position == RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                return
            }

            if (position == parent.adapter.itemCount - 1) {
                // Add padding to the last item. You should probably use a @dimen resource.
                outRect?.bottom = 200
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: Nice solution! Could you explain how to set a margin instead of a padding, if it is possible?

Answer (score 1):

I have a simple solution, may not be the best, but it does the job, just create a View with height as the height of an appBar (toolbar) with `actionBarSize` , the height of the appbar and the bottomnav are the same, so you can constrain your recyclerview to the top of this view, doing this it will not be covered by your bottomnav

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.pedidos.PedidoFragment">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/view3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Give some static height in dp for BottomNavigationView instead of wrap_content because your parent layout i,e coordinator layout extends framelayout which its default behavior is placing its child views one above the other. Thats y your fragment container is covered up by botomnavigationview.

Comment: or give static height for fragment container

Comment: or remove your coordinator layout replace with relative layout and add rules to its child views to achieve your ui

Answer (score -1):

In the main content that you are included into your layout. Give the margin bottom to the recycler view.
Because recycler view is hide behind the bottom navigation view